# Bash how pipe sort, find and grep

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to write a shell script that take the a line of a file that contain a specific number, the problem is that i need this file sorted because i need the line of the last file with some specific name. 
I have write this code but it seems doesn't work

```
sort -n | find -name '*foo*' -exec grep -r -F '11111' {} \;
```

Is really important that the files are sorted because i need to search in the last file. The files name are of type "res_*yyyy*_*mm*_*dd*_foo" and they have to be ordered by *yyyy* and if are the same by *mm* and so

Comment: What does your directory hierarchy look like? What is `*foo*`?

Comment: edited the question, *foo* because i search only for file that have in the name

Comment: I'd do the find first, then the sort, then a tail -1 (to get the last file) then the grep.

Comment: What about my other question?

Comment: $home/input_output.1/inp.1/old_res23403 that's the hierarchy

Comment: No, that's a single file (that doesn't even match the pattern in your question), not a hierarchy.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: no the single file are home/input_output.1/inp.1/old_res23403/res_2018_03_12_foo.csv

Comment: Are they all in this one directory?

Comment: yes, but there are other file like res_2011_02_06_bar.csv

Comment: What if there are no matching lines in the last file? What if there are multiple matching lines in the last file? What results do you want then?

Comment: i'm sure there isn't multiple result, but if there are no matching lines i want check the file before, until i find the line. and I'm sure that in one file there is the line

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the following would do it:

```
cd home/input_output.1/inp.1/old_res23403/
ls -1 | sort -r | xargs cat -- | grep '11111' | head -n1
```

`ls -1` produces a list of filenames in the current directory, one per line.

`sort -r` sorts them in reverse alphabetical order, which (given that your names use a big-endian date format) puts the latest files first.

`xargs cat --` concatenates the contents of all those files.

`grep '11111'` finds all lines containing `11111`.

`head -n1` limits results to the first such line.

In effect this gives you the first matching line of the files in reverse order, i.e. the last such line.